# Items from a custom list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a custom listview built with a simple adapter.
When i click the item on the listview, i want the different items on that item.
Example: my listview has two text fields and a ImageView field.
So when i click the item on the listview, how do i get the first text separately and the second  one separately.

```
    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_header_row, weather_data);
            listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);  

            listView1.setClickable(true);
            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            //want to get the specific items...like R.id.txt1 and R.id.rtxt1

              }
            });
```

And this is my Listview defined and the holder...

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View row = convertView;
WeatherHolder holder = null;

if(row == null)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new WeatherHolder();
    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    holder.txtRating=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.rtxt1);

    row.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
    holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
}

Weather weather = data[position];
holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.wtitle);
//holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.wicon);
holder.imgIcon.setImageDrawable(weather.wicon);
holder.txtRating.setText(weather.wrating); 
return row;
} 

static class WeatherHolder
{
//Bitmap imgIcon;
ImageView imgIcon;
TextView txtTitle;
TextView txtRating;
}
}
```

and the Holder values are ..

```
public class Weather {

public Drawable wicon;  
public String wtitle;
public String wrating;
public Weather(){
super();
}

public Weather(String icon, String title,String rating) {
    super();
    //this.wicon=LoadImageFromWeb(icon);

    this.wicon=LoadImageFromWebOperations(icon);
    this.wtitle = title;
    this.wrating=rating;
}


public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just use the the passed View (arg1 in your case):

```
WeatherHolder holder = (WeatherHolder) arg1.getTag();
```

Since you haven't posted the entire code, most likely you could also use the passed position.

HTH

Comment: Hey I have updated the post with the complete code...please check again... because what ever you suggested crashed

Answer (score 0):

You could either look for the views you want in the `View` representing the second parameter:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View rowView, int position, long id) {
    String firsttext = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt1)).getText().toString();
    String secondtext = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rtxt1)).getText().toString();
}
```

or you could use the [`getItemAtPosition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) method on the first parameter if you properly implemented the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View rowView, int position, long id) {
    Weather rowData = (Weather) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);    
    // get the data from rowData;
}
```